# I have 4 Tf modules deployed Azure us-c region. How I deploy 1 of these module to both us-c & Eastregion using env_east.tfvars & env_east.tfvars files

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a main.tf file that contains a module named config_graph_service_module. I need to deploy this module specifically to the East region. Currently, I have an env_east.tfvars file, and I want

```
locals {
  //This local variable is to build the resource group name
  resource_group_name            = "${var.platform_name}-${var.environment}-${var.location_short}-rg"
  app_insights_name              = var.environment == "prd" ? format("%s-%s-%s", "mbr-portal", var.location_short, "app-insights") : format("%s-%s-%s-%s", "mbr-portal", var.environment, var.location_short, "app-insights")
  key_vault_name                 = var.environment == "prd" ? format("%s-%s-%s", "mbr-portal", var.location_short, "kv") : format("%s-%s-%s-%s", "mbr-portal", var.environment, var.location_short, "kv")
  vnet_name                      = var.environment == "prd" ? format("%s-%s-%s-%s", "mbr-portal", var.environment, var.location_short, "vnet") : format("%s-%s-%s-%s", "mbr-portal", var.environment, var.location_short, "vnet")
  apim_name                      = var.environment == "prd" ? format("%s-%s-%s-%s", "mbr-portal", var.environment, var.location_short, "api-mgt") : format("%s-%s-%s-%s", "mbr-portal", var.environment, var.location_short, "api-mgt")
  gremlin_db_name                = "config-graph"
  gremlin_cosmos_central_db_name = var.environment == "prd" ? format("%s-cosmosdb", local.gremlin_db_name) : format("%s-%s-cosmosdb", local.gremlin_db_name, var.environment)
  gremlin_cosmos_east_db_name    = var.environment == "prd" ? format("%s-%s-cosmosdb", local.gremlin_db_name, var.location_short) : format("%s-%s-%s-cosmosdb", local.gremlin_db_name, var.location_short, var.environment)
  gremlin_cosmos_db_name         = var.location_short == "us-c" ? local.gremlin_cosmos_central_db_name : local.gremlin_cosmos_east_db_name
  config-graph-cors_file_location   = var.environment == "prd" ? "./apim_policies/config-graph-cors-prod.xml" : "./apim_policies/config-graph-cors.xml"
  # Tags to include on each resource
  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
    Project     = var.project
    Createdby   = "Terraform"
    Owner       = var.owner
    Terraform   = true
    ASKID       = var.askid
    Dynatrace   = "mbr-portal"
  }
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = local.vnet_name
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "config_graph_service_subnet_id" {
  name                 = "config-graph-service-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "config_cag_ingestion_subnet_id" {
  name                 = "config-cag-ingestion-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "config_service_dataload_subnet_id" {
  name                 = "config-service-dataload-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "config_admin_app_subnet_id" {
  name                 = "config-admin-app-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "function_private_endpoint_subnet_id" {
  name                 = "${var.project}-function-private-endpoint-snet-${var.environment}"
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  name                = local.key_vault_name
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_application_insights" "app_insights" {
  name                = local.app_insights_name
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "privatelink_dns_zone" {
  name                = "privatelink.azurewebsites.net"
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "privatelink_blob_dns_zone" {
  name                = "privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "gremlin_cosmosdb" {
  name                = local.gremlin_cosmos_db_name
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_api_management" "apim" {
  name                = local.apim_name
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
}

# Create Graph Config Service Function 
module "config_graph_service_module" {
  source                              = "./modules/config_graph_service"
  resource_group_name                 = local.resource_group_name
  environment                         = var.environment
  location                            = var.location
  location_short                      = var.location_short
  portal_tenant_id                    = var.portal_tenant_id
  key_vault_id                        = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  key_vault_uri                       = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.vault_uri
  subnet_id                           = data.azurerm_subnet.config_graph_service_subnet_id.id
  app_insights_instrumentation_key    = data.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights.instrumentation_key
  app_insights_connection_string      = data.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights.connection_string
  function_private_endpoint_subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.function_private_endpoint_subnet_id.id
  private_dns_zone_name               = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.privatelink_dns_zone.name
  privatelink_blob_dns_id             = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.privatelink_blob_dns_zone.id
  privatelink_dns_id                  = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.privatelink_dns_zone.id
  config_graph_service_configuration  = var.config_graph_service_configuration
  front_door_id                       = var.front_door_id
  asp_tier_premium                    = var.asp_tier_premium
  asp_size_premium                    = var.asp_size_premium
  default_webapp_count                = var.default_webapp_count
  min_webapp_count                    = var.min_webapp_count
  max_webapp_count                    = var.max_webapp_count
  autoscale_email_to                  = var.autoscale_email_to
  primary_master_key                  = data.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.gremlin_cosmosdb.primary_key
  endpoint                            = data.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.gremlin_cosmosdb.endpoint
  gremlin_db_endpoint                 = "wss://${data.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.gremlin_cosmosdb.name}.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com:443/"
  service_bus_sku                     = var.service_bus_sku
  import_data_queue_name              = "configraphservicedataqueue"
  tags                                = local.tags

  depends_on = [
    data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault,
    data.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights,
    data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet,
    data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.privatelink_dns_zone,
    data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.privatelink_blob_dns_zone,
    data.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.gremlin_cosmosdb
  ]
}

# Create Config Graph Rest API  
module "config_graph_rest_api_module" {
  source                                    = "./modules/config_graph_rest_api"
  resource_group_name                       = local.resource_group_name
  environment                               = var.environment
  environment_desc                          = var.environment_desc
  location                                  = var.location
  location_short                            = var.location_short
  config_graph_rest_api_default_hostname     = one(module.config_graph_service_module[*].data_config_graph_service_function_host_name)
  config_graph_rest_api_name                = one(module.config_graph_service_module[*].data_config_graph_service_function_name)
  apim_name                                 = data.azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  config-graph-cors_file_location           = local.config-graph-cors_file_location 
  tags                                      = local.tags

}  
# Create Config Service Dataload Function 
module "config_service_dataload_module" {
  source                                    = "./modules/config_service_dataload"
  resource_group_name                       = local.resource_group_name
  environment                               = var.environment
  location                                  = var.location
  location_short                            = var.location_short
  portal_tenant_id                          = var.portal_tenant_id
  key_vault_id                              = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  key_vault_uri                             = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.vault_uri
  subnet_id                                 = data.azurerm_subnet.config_service_dataload_subnet_id.id
  app_insights_instrumentation_key          = data.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights.instrumentation_key
  app_insights_connection_string            = data.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights.connection_string
  config_service_dataload_configuration     = var.config_service_dataload_configuration
  function_private_endpoint_subnet_id       = data.azurerm_subnet.function_private_endpoint_subnet_id.id
  private_dns_zone_name                     = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.privatelink_dns_zone.name
  privatelink_blob_dns_id                   = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.privatelink_blob_dns_zone.id
  privatelink_dns_id                        = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.privatelink_dns_zone.id
  front_door_id                             = var.front_door_id
  endpoint                                  = data.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.gremlin_cosmosdb.endpoint
  config_graph_service_api_default_hostname = module.config_graph_service_module.data_config_graph_service_function_host_name
  config_service_df_container_name          = var.config_service_df_container_name
  tags                                      = local.tags

  depends_on = [
  //  module.config_cag_ingestion_module,
    module.config_graph_service_module
  ]
}


module "config_service_webapp" {
  source                              = "./modules/config_service_webapp"
  environment                         = var.environment
  environment_desc                    = var.environment_desc
  tags                                = local.tags
  resource_group_name                 = local.resource_group_name
  location                            = var.location
  location_short                      = var.location_short
  front_door_id                       = var.front_door_id
  key_vault_id                        = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  key_vault_uri                       = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.vault_uri
  key_vault_name                      = data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.name
  instrumentation_key                 = data.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights.instrumentation_key
  app_insights_connection_string      = data.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights.connection_string
  subnet_id                           = data.azurerm_subnet.config_admin_app_subnet_id.id
  portal_tenant_id                    = var.portal_tenant_id
  config_service_webapp_configuration = var.config_service_webapp_configuration
  asp_tier_standard                   = var.asp_tier_standard
  asp_size_standard                   = var.asp_size_standard
  //dev_monitoring_action_group_id      = one(data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.dev_monitoring_action_group[*].id)
  //devops_monitoring_action_group_id   = one(data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.devops_monitoring_action_group[*].id)
  //l3_monitoring_action_group_id       = one(data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.l3_monitoring_action_group[*].id)
  //l3_mock_monitoring_action_group_id  = one(data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.l3_mock_monitoring_action_group[*].id)

  depends_on = [
   // module.config_cag_ingestion_module,
    module.config_graph_service_module
  ]

}
```

I just need to deploy the config-graph module to the east region with the help of env_region.tfvars file.

env_region.tfvars is here

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Parameter file for ClockWork Portal Performance Environment
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The Azure region
location = "East US 2"

# Short form of Azure region, used for naming resources
location_short = "us-e"

# Azure Subscription
subscription_id = "[SECRET]"

# The environment name, used for tagging resources
environment_desc = "performance"

# Short form of environment, used for naming resources
environment = "prf"

# Application or componentname, used for naming resources
platform_name = "mbr-portal"

# Project
project = "mbr-portal"

# Owner
owner = "[SECRET]"

# ASKID
askid = "[SECRET]"

# Front door ID
front_door_id = "[SECRET]"

# ACR specific
acr_sku = "basic"

# Common key vault information
shared_key_vault_rg   = "mbr-portal-statefiles-rg"
shared_key_vault_name = "mbr-portal-common-kv"

# CosmosDB Failover Region
cosmos_db_failover_location     = "East US"
cosmos_db_eastfailover_location = "East US2"

# SSO cache Service Bus sku
service_bus_sku = "Standard"
capacity        = 0

# Not being use right now
tls_certificate_key_vault = {
  resource_group_name        = "mbr-portal-tst-us-c-rg"
  key_vault_name             = "mbr-portal-tst-us-c-kv"
  front_door_tls_cert_secret = "[SECRET]"
}

# Cosmos db throughput's
cache_cosmosdb_throughput  = 4800
config_cosmosdb_throughput = 800
ip_range_filter            = "[SECRET]"

# Version secrets in keyvault 10 = 1.0, 11 = 1.1
uhcei_secret_version    = "10"
uhcmr_secret_version    = "10"
uhcmrpcp_secret_version = "10"
optumrx_secret_version  = "10"

# ASP SKUs
asp_tier_premium  = "PremiumV2"
asp_size_premium  = "P1v2"
asp_tier_standard = "PremiumV3"
asp_size_standard = "P1v3"

# AutoScaleProfile instance counts
default_webapp_count = 6
min_webapp_count     = 6
max_webapp_count     = 8

# Auto scale notification Email-to
autoscale_email_to = ["[SECRET]", "[SECRET]", "[SECRET]"]

config_graph_service_configuration = {
  "GREMLIN_DB_NAME"               = "GraphConfigDB",
  "GREMLIN_DB_COLLECTION"         = "ConfigSettings"
  "GREMLIN_DB_PARTITION_KEY"      = "_partitionKey"
  "APOLLO_INTROSPECTION"          = "true"
  "SERVICEBUS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME"  = "config_graph_servicebus_subscription"
  "SERVICEBUS_TOPIC"              = "config_graph_servicebus_topic"
  "AZURE_TIME_TRIGGER"            = "63113852000"
  "EXP_SKYLINE_TOKEN_URL"         = "[SECRET]"
  "AZURE_DF_TOKEN_URL"            = "[SECRET]"
  "AZURE_DATA_RETRIEVAL_URL"       = "[SECRET]"
}
```

Comment: Can you share `env_region.tfvars` file to resolve the issue? @Vikash Sharma

Comment: Added the asked files

Comment: Still are you facing the blocker? @Vikash Sharma

Comment: yes it is still a blocker for me and checking it on everyday